# IOS HealthKit Error:Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement

Tags: ios, healthkit, entitlements

I'm taking out the HealthKit capability from my IOS app (Xcode 8.3.3, swift 3, IOS 10.2). I edited the app ID and turned off the HealthKit Service In developer account and created a new provisional certificate for signing that goes with this app ID. I've also turned off the HealthKit switch in Xcode capabilities, I verified there is nothing in the info.plist associated with HealthKit.

But I still get this error:

Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement.}

Greatly appreciate if you can please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any other targets in your app?

Comment: No, but there is an .entitlement  file floating around in the Health folder, like below which I think is the source, what I need to do to ignore it at build time since I'm not enabling the health app portion of the code.   <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: Adding the key <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key> <true/> </dict> to exportOptions.plist did not work for me.